# What is reference counter and how does it work?

Tags: c

I've been writing code, and I'm in a point where I should have another program calling my library. I should make a reference counter for the output of my library. Basic idea as I have understood is that, I need to have reference counter struct inside my struct that I want to pass around. So my questions are following:

1. What should I keep in mind when making a reference counter?
2. What are complete don'ts when making a reference counter?
3. Is there really detailed examples where to start with this?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: Don't understand what you are talking about.... "reference counter for the output" ???

Comment: Are you sure you need reference counting? Maybe you just need a function to free whatever you've passed to the calling program? Even if you have reference counting, you still need to have some function to be called by that library. Otherwise the counter would not be decreased anyway...

Comment: Output is a hash table made from structs. I need the reference counter so I know when the calling program doesn't need that hash table anymore and then I can release all memory allocated for it.
It would be nice to know also why I get minus for my question. I really don't know these things and it would be nice to know what's wrong with my question so I could find info about subjects without having to ask all the time.

Comment: What would trigger decrementing the counter in your scenario? Not accessing the memory anymore might be a bit tricky to detect...

Comment: Decrementing could be done with a function like you said, and that function would be called when calling program quits using the hash table. Another function would be called every time hash table is used and that would increment the counter.

Comment: You shouldn't need reference counters for this.  Your library only needs to supply a function to free the given memory.  It's up to the caller to decide when it doesn't need that memory anymore and call your cleanup function.

Comment: Ok, thanks! What would then be situations where I'd want to use reference counter?

Comment: Here's an example lib I made that takes advantage of reference counting to use shared pointers https://gist.github.com/BuonOmo/a4467a2701920625d40f4461749ef0f1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reference counting allows clients of your library to keep reference objects created by your library on the heap and allows you to keep track of how many references are still active. When the reference count goes to zero you can safely free the memory used by the object. It is a way to implement basic "garbage collection".

In C++, you can do this more easily, by using "smart pointers" that manage the reference count through the constructor and destructor, but it sounds like you are looking to do it in C.

You need to be very clear on the protocol that you expect users of your libraries to follow when accessing your objects so that they properly communicate when a new reference is created or when a reference is no longer needed. Getting this wrong will either prematurely free memory that is still being referenced or cause memory to never be freed (memory leak).

Basically, You include a reference count in your struct, that gets incremented each time that your library returns the struct.

You also need to provide a function that releases the reference:

```
struct Object {
  int ref;
  ....
}

Object* getObject (...) {
  Object *p = .... // find or malloc the object
  p->ref++;
  return p;
}

void releaseReference (Object* p) {
  p->ref--;
  if (p->ref == 0) free(p);
}

void grabReference (Object* p) {
  p->ref++;
}
```

Use `grabReference()` if a client of your library passes a reference to another client (in the above example, the initial caller of your library doesn't need to call `grabReference()`)

If your code is multi-threaded then you need to make sure that you handle this correctly when incrementing or decrementing references

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot and now I got this problem fixed. The program now works as supposed :)

Comment: Thanks, please can you mark that the question is answered :)